# How to let the users download JSON & CSV File in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

On my Django project, I have scraped data in a JSON & CSV format. I want to let the users download the JSON and CSV files.

The below code generates the files in my django project directory.

**views.py**

```
final = json.dumps(sorted_result, indent=2)
with open("webscraping_dataset.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(final)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": name, "Price": price, "URL":URL})
df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

How should I implement it in my Django project so that the users can download those files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already generated your CSV and JSON, I think you need to first return those in your views.py:

```
final = json.dumps(sorted_result, indent=2)
with open("webscraping_dataset.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(final)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": name, "Price": price, "URL":URL})

csv_file = df.to_csv("data.csv")
json_file = "webscraping_dataset.json"


return csv_file, json_file
```

Then, you need to add a URL to urls.py to point to the views.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import download_files

urlpatterns = [
     path('download/', [NAME OF YOUR FUNCTION THAT RETURNS CSV & JSON]
 ]
```

When a user requests the URL, /download/, it should call your function and return the CSV and JSON generated.

This article might provide some more clarity:
https://www.etutorialspoint.com/index.php/252-django-generate-and-download-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

**a)  download via HTML page:**

typically you would handle those generated files as media files (like if a user uploads a user image etc. and you need to store and serve it).

in settings.py define

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "media/")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

in views use the MEDIA_ROOT (maybe add some subfolders to MEDIA_ROOT):

```
with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,"webscraping_dataset.json", "w") as outfile:
...
```

add MEDIA_ROOT to context in views:

```
context = {
    'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL,
     ...
}
return render(request, '.../xxx.html', context)
```

and in HTML use

```
<a href="{{media_url}}webscraping_dataset.json">
```

You would then still have to care about that media files are served by the HTTP Server.

if you use Apache in http.conf something like

```
Alias /media/ absolute_path_like_defined_as_MEDIA_ROOT
```

**b)  download directly from view:**

if you want to return the file directly from the view without html page:

CSV

```
csv_output = df.to_csv("data.csv")
response = HttpResponse(csv_output, content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=webscraping_dataset.csv'

return response
```

JSON:

```
final = json.dumps(sorted_result, indent=2)
return JsonResponse(final)
```